# String replace doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, string, replace, safari

The string `"MM/DD/YYYY".replace(/.?YYYY.?/, '');` returns `MM/DD` in Chrome but Safari returns empty string. Why is that? Which method works uniformly across all browsers?

Comment: Just curious why are using a regex for trying to replace that. I mean why not just string.replace('/YYYY', '');

Comment: YYYY could be located anywhere in the string even beginning..hence a regex,

Comment: Interesting. If you remove the trailing .? it is fine. What is the las .? doing exactly? seems werid to remove that.

Comment: @epascarello: That works :) Please post this as answer! So I'm looking for a result of  "MM/DD" if its above string. Wonder how the above works as expected in FF and Chrome but not Safari!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem previously. I added an empty string then it worked. For some reason, I had to add an empty string to my string for Safari to acknowledge that the variable was a string.

var date = "mm/dd/yyyyy"+"",
then do -- "date".replace(/.?YYYY.?/, '');

Comment: nope doesn't work..  format = format + '';format = format.replace(/.?YYYY.?/, '');

Comment: I tried removing ".?" after yyyy in replace method. It's working for me in safari and chrome. just try using "MM/DD/YYYY".replace(/.?YYYY/, '');

Answer (score -2):

Have you checked the charsets used at your project and at your browsers?

Comment: how does that matter? could you provide an example of how it matters?

Comment: Recently I had a similar issue on a project of mine on string formatting due to special chars on UTF-8 and another charset from a 3rd party app. The replace method could not find the exact char I was looking for.

Comment: E.g.: "Space" char and "%20".